# How can I call a function in one file that is defined within another, with both being in one main file?

Tags: python, external

Let's say I have three different python files, `a.py`, `b.py`, and `main.py`.

I have defined a function `getExternal()` in `a.py`, which I want to call in `b.py`. Both `a.py` and `b.py` have had all of their functions imported into `main.py`, however when I run the code in `main.py` which references the function in question, I get the following error message: `name 'getExternal' is not defined`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, there is: you need to import the function where you want to use it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: If you don't mind showing a [mre], it's currently not exactly clear why what you have done doesn't work. I can only guess what has already been written as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your examples, import `getExternal` in `b.py` like this:

```py
from a import getExternal
```